# Neural network always outputs a value close to 0.5

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

```
import numpy
import scipy.special
import random

data = [[3, 1.5, 1], [2, 1, 0], [4, 1.5, 1], [3, 1, 0], [3.5, 0.5, 1], [2, 0.5, 0], [5.5, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]

# neural network class definition
class neuralNetwork:


    # initialise the neural network
    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        # set number of nodes in each input, hidden, output layer
        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.hnodes = hiddennodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        # link weight matrices, wih and who
        # weights inside the arrays are w_i_j, where link is from node i to node j in the next layer
        # w11 w21
        # w12 w22 etc 
        self.wih = numpy.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.inodes, -0.5), (self.hnodes, self.inodes))
        self.who = numpy.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.hnodes, -0.5), (self.onodes, self.hnodes))

        # learning rate
        self.lr = learningrate

        # activation function is the sigmoid function
        self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)


    # train the neural network
    def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
        # convert inputs list to 2d array
        inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        targets = numpy.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T

        # calculate signals into hidden layer
        hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        # calculate the signals emerging from hidden layer
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

        # calculate signals into final output layer
        final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        # calculate the signals emerging from final output layer
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

        # output layer error is the (target - actual)
        output_errors = targets - final_outputs
        # hidden layer error is the output_errors, split by weights, recombined at hidden nodes
        hidden_errors = numpy.dot(self.who.T, output_errors) 

        # update the weights for the links between the hidden and output layers
        self.who += self.lr * numpy.dot((output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 - final_outputs)), numpy.transpose(hidden_outputs))

        # update the weights for the links between the input and hidden layers
        self.wih += self.lr * numpy.dot((hidden_errors * hidden_outputs * (1.0 - hidden_outputs)), numpy.transpose(inputs))


    # query the neural network
    def query(self, inputs_list):
        # convert inputs list to 2d array
        inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

        # calculate signals into hidden layer
        hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        # calculate the signals emerging from hidden layer
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

        # calculate signals into final output layer
        final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        # calculate the signals emerging from final output layer
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

        return final_outputs

net = neuralNetwork(2, 1, 1, 0.1)

EPOCHS = 50
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    random.shuffle(data)
    for point in data:
        training_data = [point[0], point[1]]
        target = point[2]
        net.train(training_data, target)

net.query([3, 1.5])
```

This is my code that keeps on giving an output close to 0.5. Why does this happen and how do I fix this? Usually, the outputs are around 0.45 to 0.55. Please give me the specific places where it can be modified to gie the desired output. By the way, all credits to this code goes to "Make Your Own Neural Network" by Tariq Rashd. I am just trying to implement his neural network class to a toy dataset i created.

Comment: I think that your neural network is predicting the mean of the input data, since you are outputting either a 0 or a 1. If there is no actual pattern in the data, then it will just simply predict the mean as this is the best answer it can give.

Comment: I disagree with the fact that the data does not have any pattern. I graphed the points where if the target is 1, the point is red and if the target is 0, the point is blue, with matplotlib

Comment: for 3, 1.5 the answer is 1, but for 3, 1 answer is 0. This is pretty confusing pattern for such a dummy network. Also your output error never decreases actually, so the prediction will be around at mean.

Answer (score -1):

Just put more iterations there `EPOCHS = 50` and it will work
But when i said more iterations i didnt mean 55 or 60 ,i meant 10000